# Simple QGraphicsScene program

Tags: python, pyqt

At the [documentation for `QGraphicsScene`](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsScene.html), there is a simple example that does not work as written. I've written a fix that *does* work, and am curious if it could be improved.

From the docs (does not work as is):

> ```
> scene = QGraphicsScene()
> scene.addText("Hello, world!")
> view = QGraphicsView(&scene)
> view.show()
> ```

Fixed version that *does* work:

```
from PySide import QtGui
import sys

class MyFirstScene(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.scene=QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.addText("Hello, world!")
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    firstScene = MyFirstScene()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My question is whether I can simplify this more, making it more like the example in the documentation. I tried doing it without making the scene an attribute of `QWidget`, which breaks it. But perhaps I'm missing a simpler working implementation of the documentation's skeleton?

Comment: Did you try simply to omit the `&`? Works for me in PyQt, don't know about PySide.

Comment: @JanneKarila  That was the first thing I tried, and Python crashed (this was both PySide and PyQt). If you got that four-liner from the docs to work, I'd really like to see the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This complete script works for me with PyQt on Windows, displays a small window and waits for me to close it.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
scene.addText("Hello, world!")
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()

app.exec_()
```

A `QApplication` object must be created before any other GUI objects.

Comment: Nice! This is a definite improvement on my example. Follows the spirit of the documentation, and also the output looks nicer because the scene is not wrapped in a QWidget.